# J2ME SIP connection VIA header

Tags: java, java-me, sip

I send INVITE to a sip server in a J2ME app and use rtp for data transmision.There is a conflict in VIA header which is that,implecite via header contain UDP instead of rtp. But I haven't use 'upd' any where in my code.If we consider the JAINSIP we can modify the VIA header header.But j2m2 api doesn't allow to modify the VIA header([here](http://mobilezoo.biz/jsr/180/javax/microedition/sip/SipClientConnection.html#CRED_EXAMPLE1)).

How can I solve this?how to avoid implicitly adding udp to VIA header in my request.Where I should see again??
Here is my sending INVITE Code

```
 try {  final String ip = scn.getLocalAddress();
        contact = "sip:user@" + scn.getLocalAddress() + ":" + scn.getLocalPort();
        scc = (SipClientConnection)  Connector.open("sip:user@xxx.xxx.xxx.x:5060;transport=tcp");
        scc.setListener(this);
        scc.initRequest("INVITE", scn);

        scc.setRequestURI("sip:user@xxx.xxx.xxx.x:5060;transport=tcp");
        scc.setHeader("From", "sip:user@" + scn.getLocalAddress() + ":" + scn.getLocalPort() + ";transport=tcp");

        scc.setHeader("To", "sip:user@xxx.xxx.xxx.x:5060;transport=tcp");
        scc.setHeader("Contact", contact);
        System.out.println("Session id is :" + sId);

        scc.setHeader("Session-Id", sId);
        scc.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/sdp");
        String sdp = "....";
        OutputStream os = scc.openContentOutputStream();
        os.write(sdp.getBytes());
        os.close();
```